# add label to filled.contour

Tags: r, statistics

Wondering what is the parameter for x-axis and y-axis text label and the main text label? I referred R help (by `? filled.contour`), but still confused. Show an example, wondering how to add x-axis and y-axis text label and the main text label in below example. Thanks.

```
    require(MASS)
    b       <- log10(rgamma(1000,6,3))
    a       <- log10((rweibull(1000,8,2)))
    density <- kde2d(a,b,n=100)
    filled.contour(density,color.palette=colorRampPalette(
                  c('white','blue','yellow','red','darkred')))
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: The method is the same as `plot()`. `filled.contour(density,color.palette=colorRampPalette(c('white','blue','yellow','red','darkred')), xlab="xlab", ylab="ylab", main="main")`

Comment: @cuttlefish44 You should probably post that as an answer. Seems to be correct.

Comment: @Hack-R; You’re right, thanks for your advice. I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: @cuttlefish44, thanks and vote up, it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cuttlefish44 mentioned, the method is the same as plot().

```
filled.contour(density,color.palette=colorRampPalette(c('white','blue','yellow'‌​
,'red','darkred')), xlab="xlab", ylab="ylab", main="main")
```

Comment: Thanks datahero, vote up and mark your reply as answer.